# What's the difference between creating one fargate profile for each availability zone, and creating a single profile that spans multiple AZs?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, karpenter

I'm in the process of creating fargate profiles for my AWS EKS cluster using terraform. In [this example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/blob/v19.5.1/examples/karpenter/main.tf#L114) for the Terraform Karpenter module, they have a loop that creates one profile for each of the 3 availability zones used in the example:

```
  fargate_profiles = { 
    for i in range(3) :
      "karpenter-${element(split("-", local.azs[i]), 2)}" => {
        selectors = [
          { namespace = "karpenter" }
        ]
        # We want to create a profile per AZ for high availability
        subnet_ids = [element(module.vpc.private_subnets, i)]
      }
  }
```

Why is this necessary? What's the difference between this and creating a single profile that is attached to 3 zones? Something like this:

```
  fargate_profiles = {
    "karpenter" = {
      selectors = [
        { namespace = "karpenter" }
      ]
      subnet_ids = var.vpc_private_subnets
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One profile one AZ allows you to deploy pod in specific AZ. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-profile.html):

> Amazon EKS and Fargate spread pods across each of the subnets that's
> defined in the Fargate profile. However, you might end up with an
> uneven spread. If you must have an even spread, use two Fargate
> profiles. Even spread is important in scenarios where you want to
> deploy two replicas and don't want any downtime. We recommend that
> each profile has only one subnet.